# Non Equality Join on Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, bigdata, geospatial

I am trying to emulate a SQL query on hive, where I grab data from two tables that **do not** have a common field.

The two tables are geometric (GeoHive) and one contains a bunch of points (one for each record) and the other one a grid (one cell for each record). The objective is to count how many points fit inside each cell.

[image]

The join condition between the two tables is the geometric function itself. This is how I do it in PostGIS:

```
SELECT g.geom, count(t.geom) AS cnt
   FROM grid g, points t
WHERE st_contains(g.geom,t.geom) GROUP BY g.geom
```

Hive does not accept the multiple select, so I have to perform a join. I thought something like this could work:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM grid JOIN points WHERE   
 ST_Contains(grid.geom,points.geom) GROUP BY grid.geom;
```

, but hive [silently ignores my condition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins):

*"Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce job"*

Anyone has any ideas of how to refactor such query on Hive?

Comment: Did you try a cross join? Also is it easy to transform st_contains to an equality?

Comment: Thanks for your reply: I have in fact been trying a cross-join for the past four hours, without any result yet.... SELECT count(geom) FROM grid_bcn CROSS JOIN geo_tweets WHERE ST_Contains(grid_bcn.geom,geo_tweets.location) GROUP BY grid_bcn.geom limit 10;

Comment: transforming ST_CONTAIS into an equality is a good head cue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer my own question, to state that my query attempt was correct: it was failing for other reasons, that have nothing to do with syntax.

```
SELECT count(grid.geom) as ptcnt FROM grid JOIN points WHERE
ST_Contains(grid.geom,points.geom) GROUP BY grid.geom;
```

This is actually equivalent to writing:

```
SELECT count(grid.geom) as ptcnt FROM grid JOIN points ON(TRUE) WHERE
ST_Contains(grid.geom,points.geom) GROUP BY grid.geom;
```

Hive does not in fact support non-equality joins, so I set the join condition to "TRUE", and filter my results on the "WHERE" clause.

Apparently this is a pretty standard behaviour for spatial joins, as you can read [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Spatial+queries).